# Require old password to change new password authlogic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have a _form.html.erb partial that will send user input to the update method in the controller

```
<div id='myaccount-profile_name_form' class='clearfix'>
  <fieldset id="myaccount-profile" class='five columns'>
     <ul id="posting_classified_form">
       <li>
         <%= f.label :first_name %>
         <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First Name" %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= f.label :last_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= f.label :form_birth_date, "Birthday" %>
          <%= f.text_field :form_birth_date, :class => 'ui-yearpicker', :placeholder => "mm/dd/yyyy" %>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id='myaccount-profile_form' class='clearfix' >
  <fieldset id="myaccount-profile-password" class='five '>
    <ul id="posting_classified_form">
      <li>
        <%= f.label :current_password, "Current Password", :placeholder => "We need your current password to confirm your changes", :required => true %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= f.label :password, "New Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm", :style => "white-space:normal;" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit 'Update' , :class => 'goButton', :style => 'width:auto;float:right;'%></div>
</div>
```

this is the edit/update methods in the controller

```
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:current_password])
      binding.pry
      @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice]  = "Successfully updated user."
      redirect_to umarket_index_url
    else
      flash[:notice]  = "An error occurred while updating user please try again."
      redirect_to umarket_index_url
 #     render :edit
    end
  end
```

We are using the authlogic gem to do authentication. I found valid_password? from authlogic doc. I want to give the user the ability to change password only after the user enters the correct password.

The server logs look like this

```
Started GET "/myaccount/overview/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 11:16:07 -0400
Processing by Myaccount::OverviewsController#edit as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1
  Rendered myaccount/overviews/_form.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered myaccount/overviews/edit.html.erb (5.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 5.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started PUT "/myaccount/overview" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 11:16:14 -0400
Processing by Myaccount::OverviewsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b01gMlAQOJpu6Zu+mg+M4v2VYfm0AZvTAfKXa+ArJxU=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Judy", "last_name"=>"Ngai", "email"=>"judy.ngai1228@gmail.com", "form_birth_date"=>"spree@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/umarket
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

The password didn't get change. There are no errors from the logs. I don't use authlogic so I am quite confused.

Comment: after executing `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` try looking into `@user.errors` to see if there's any validation failing

Answer (score 1):

What I feel wrong about your code is that you're current_password and new password fields have the same name which is `user['password']` in your case. Try changing the name as specified in the code below. I have pasted both the action and view code for your reference.

Note: Params is a hash, and it can not have the same key repeated which is what your trying to do. Just change the names and it should work fine.

Here is the code

```
def update_password  
  redirect_to user_path, alert: 'The current password you entered is not correct!' and return unless current_user.valid_password?(params[:user][:current_password], true)

  current_user.password = params[:user][:password]
  current_user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]
  if current_user.save
    redirect_to user_path, notice: 'Your password has been updated'
  else
    redirect_to user_path, alert: current_user.errors.to_a.join("<br>")
  end
end
```

And the form looks like this

```
%div{style: "display: none;", class: "updatePassWord curved curved-sm"}
= form_for current_user, url: update_password_user_path, html: {id: 'changePassForm'}, method: :put do |f|
  .row{:class => "form-group"}
    = f.password_field :current_password, class: "input-sm required passwordValidator", placeholder: "#{t('form_placeholder.current_password')}"
  .row{:class => "form-group"}
    = f.password_field :password, class: "input-sm required passwordValidator", placeholder: "#{t('form_placeholder.new_password')}"
  .row{:class => "form-group"}
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "input-sm required passwordValidator", placeholder: "#{t('form_placeholder.password_confirmation')}"
  .row{:class => "form-group"}
    = f.submit "Update My Password", class: "btn btn-success btn-cons submit"
```

Let me know if that helps